# Exact same command line produces error in Make yet succeeds if run from shell

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a problem that I just can't wrap my head around. I have a minimal example makefile that is supposed to compile a very simple .c file into an executable program.

When I run **make**, the compiler starts compiling and then produces an error message

> "T:\printOffsets.c:10:21: error: bootIfc.h: No such file or
>   directory"

Then I copy the exact same command line **make** is using to build the target and run it directly in the same Windows command shell instance, and suddenly compilation succeeds without errors!! The command line is (path names simplified):

> T:\perl\c\bin\gcc.exe T:\printOffsets.c -IT:\include\ -o
>   D:\printOffsets.exe

How do I know? Well, **make** prints the command line before it executes it, so I simply copy&paste from the shell.

I don't get it! How is this possible?? How can the exact same command work on the shell and fail if launched from within a Makefile??

I'm using GNU Make 3.82 on Windows 7, by the way.

Comment: Could you try with slashes instead of backslashes? I believe I got sometime the same problem and using slashes was better in some cases.

Comment: Also maybe Make is not using the shell you believe, may you add a target in your makefile to launch echo $(SHELL)?

Comment: @jdarthenay You are exactly right!! It is using sh.exe, not the Windows command shell! And replacing all backslashes with forward slashes fixed the problem! Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept / up-vote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When command in makefile is giving different result from shell, just make sure it is using the shell you want.

Add a phony target in your make file:

```
.PHONY:testshell

testshell:
    echo $(SHELL)
```

And run:

```
gmake testshell
```

If the result is not your favorite shell you can force it by adding a line such as this one at the beginning of your makefile:

```
SHELL=C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

If you are not sure of full path of your shell, just open a DOS console and launch:

```
where cmd
```

Edit: alternative solution

When using `sh` shell instead of `cmd` shell, you can also replaces all backslashes in commands with slashes and keep using `sh`.

Edit 2: [change shell for a single target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589300/5845470)

Comment: Is it possible to change the shell to use just for the recipe of one particular make target, but let all the other targets continue to use the default shell?

Comment: @antred No idea how one's could do that. Maybe it's possible to change value of `SHELL` but I never tried it.

Comment: @antred Maybe from bash you can launch a single cmd command with `cmd /C echo toto` for instance, and the opposite should also be possible.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Meanwhile, I found out that there's another way, too. Go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets/589300 and scroll down to the accepted answer.

Comment: @antred thanks for this link, it is indeed very interesting.